# How to Set an Object's Property using Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I am streaming and filtering values . Is there any way i can set another object value after the filter. I dont want to collect or return anything.

```
boolean b = ddlTables.stream()
    .filter(d -> d.getFieldName().equalsIgnoreCase("restrict"))
    .findFirst()
    .isPresent();

if (b) {
    validationModel.setFailMessage("Fail");
}
```

I don't want to do it in the way shown above.

I'm trying to avoid the return and `if` condition and set the value like below.

```
ddlTables.stream()
    .filter(d -> d.getFieldName().equalsIgnoreCase("restrict"))
    //  validationModel.setFailMessage("failed"); <- Need to set the object value
```

Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Using streams to modify outside data structures is not a good idea as it can have negative side effects.  The best way is to modify the object and return it in a new data structure.   There is nothing wrong with using a loop to do this.

Comment: ok , But even if its bad is there any way we can do it ?

Comment: I 100% agree not to write it if its not efficient way to code. But every time this kind of situation comes i used to think is there any way to write it .  I couldn't figure out to write it . So curious to know how to do it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the state of objects outside the stream is **discouraged** by the [*Stream API documentation*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects).

But you can leverage the functionality provided by the `Optional` class.

Method [`Optional.ifPresent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent(java.util.function.Consumer)) which allows providing an optional action in the form of `Consumer` that will be executed when result is present.

It's also worth to extract the stream-statement into a separate method (*nothing specific to streams - just the* [*Single-responsibility principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)).

```
final Model validationModel = // something

findByProperty(ddlTables, "restrict")
    .ifPresent(something -> validationModel.setFailMessage("Fail"));
```

```
public static Optional<Something> findByProperty(List<Something> list, String targetValue) {
    return list.stream()
        .filter(d -> d.getFieldName().equalsIgnoreCase(targetValue))
        .findFirst();
}
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/rQL)

Comment: am getting compile time error and Its asking me to change the return type of setFailMessage to return a consumer .

Comment: @VKP Sorry, there was a bug, amended the code. Try it again. Also note that `validationModel` shouldn't be reassigned, otherwise it would be not eligible to be used inside the lambda expression.

Comment: I am still getting error saying cannot infer functional interface type.

Comment: @VKP Sorry fixed again. Please try it out.

Comment: @VKP Here is a link to [*Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/rQL)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can offer is this.  It uses the result of the `isPresent` method to form a logical expression.  But you must always return something from a stream or print a value using a terminal operation which triggers the flow of values.  And let me reiterate that your first way of doing it was fine and that is exactly how I would do it.

```
if (ddlTables.stream().filter(d-> 
           d.getFieldName().equalsIgnoreCase("restrict")).findFirst().isPresent()) {
                            validationModel.setFailMessage("Fail");
}
```

Comment: This appears to be working , So there is no way to make it without making it as a logical expression ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware.  Sorry.  BTW, to fix your other problem, use `ifPresent(a->...)`  where   a is some local value not being used.  I believe it takes an argument.